# query a query result , return only TOP 100 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

I start a query on an MSSQL Server with the following statement

```
aquery.sql.text := ' select * from Mytable where <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>';
aquery.open; 
repeat 
   //........
until aquery.EOF
```

MyTable has 4 additional col#s :    x1,x2,y1,y2;
I want to get from above SQL Statement only the top 100 row's, but they should be rows with Maximum  Area, which means (area = abs(x1-x0) * abs(y1-y0);

What is the best solution to get only 100 records with a Maximum area, but limited with the given Basic SQL Statement ?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use (you can replace the [tag:delphi] with the SQL Server version tag) ? And do I understand it right, that you can only modify the `<XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>` part of the query ?

Comment: MSSQL Server 2008 and MSSQL Server 2012, would be nice a solution for both Server Versions.

Comment: Yes <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>  this is the query where Statement  which will be changed by the Software user ,  but I want to give him only the 100 largest objects back with the query modification

Comment: Why don't you change query to standard "SELECT TOP 100 FROM ..." clause?

Comment: is there a reason you can't change the rest of the query?  Cause Andrei has it right, `TOP 100` is the way to go

Comment: TOP 100 only gives the first 100 records of the given query, I perfer to get the 100 records with the Maximum area instead of it .

Comment: @Franz Just order the query by area and take TOP 100 in standard way.

Comment: @Andrei -> area is not yet a field of my table, a was thinking of defining a calc field and then follow your way; The question has been about a solution wizhout the calc field option

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn, it is not a standard, it is Microsoft/Sybase quirk, by the way.

Comment: @Free Yes, you right, but it is standard way to solve the task with MS SQL. So in context of the task i think it is ok to call it "standard".

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM Mytable 
ORDER BY Abs(x1-x0)*Abs(y1-y0) DESC
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought at first.  But comparing the result on my data with results obtained by another method didn't give identical  results, which is why I took the more long-winded route that did.  I'll check my results manually and take my answer down if I blundered.

Comment: guess it should by ORDER BY Abs(x1-x0)*Abs(y1-y0) DESC :-)

Comment: Cough!  Having checked my results I must have got something wrong somewhere.  Next time, maybe I should go with my first thought and not bother to check the result ;)